# What does the HUP Signal mean in brasero?

Tags: linux, gnome, compact-disc

What does it mean if brasero gets HUP signal when trying to write image on Compact disc in brasero?

Comment: @kinokijuf Seriously, you need to pause

Answer (score 0):

Based on my dire experience with Brasero, and on the advice I received from the Fedora Forums, it means 'time to ditch it and install [K3b](http://www.k3b.org/)"